# Why Does Indexing a Numpy Column Creates a Copy, But Not For Rows or 1D arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, syntax

So say I have an array named array1D:

```
array1D

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Then I take slice of it and assign its values to 22

```
slice_of_array1D = array1D[0:3]
slice_of_array1D[:] = 22
```

If I check the original array I got my slice from, the first 3 values also changes to 22

```
array1D

array([22, 22, 22,  3,  4,  5])
```

Now I understand that it is done to save memory, as the slice_of_array1D merely references array1D rather than creates a copy, which would require using array1D.copy(). However, what I am confused about is why it doesn't do that for matrices columns as well?. Here's an example:

```
array2D

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Now lets take a slice of array2D, the first column, and call it just to show how it looks:

```
slice_of_array2D = array2D[:,[0]]

slice_of_array2D

array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
```

Now let's assign the slice's values to 22, call the slice, then call the original array2D

```
slice_of_array2D[:] = 22

slice_of_array2D

array([[22],
       [22],
       [22]])

array2D

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

See how the original array2D stays unchanged? Why does this happen. Doing this for rows instead of columns does change the values in the original matrix, just like it does with 1D arrays. However, as you saw above, columns seem to be immune. Now, is there a reason/rationale for this in Python? I am asking because I am learning Python/Numpy to use it instead of MATLAB, so most of my work will use matrices and linear algebra etc. I hope maybe a logical justification on why it does that, aka understanding how Python/Numpy "thinks", would make it easier for me to work with it.

Thank you friends! I apologize for the long question but I wanted to include all information that may be relevant :)

Comment: The difference is in how you index. `[0]` makes a copy. `array2d[:, 2]` is a view. So is `array2d[:, 2:3]`

Comment: @hpaulj using `array2d[:, 2]` shows the column as a row though. It automatically transposes it I guess. I used `array2D[:,[0]]` specifically to keep the integrity of the column as a column. Also, is there a way to index a row so that it creates a copy quickly like I did when I indexed out the column?

Comment: @hpaulj okay when using `array2d[:, 2:3]` it works like if I was just viewing. I figured out how to index out a row while creating a copy. TBH creating a copy seems a ton more useful than just viewing so I will stick to it. One more thing, is there a way to index something out of a 1D array AND create a copy? I tried to include an extra set of [] but that gave me an error. Thanks!

Comment: Don't skip the numpy indexing docs.  There are enough differences that it's worth reading.

Comment: @hpaulj got it. I was studying python from youtube lectures and sololearn but I will try to read the docs to hopefully get a deeper understanding.

Comment: @user13201154 What do you mean by *"Doing this for rows instead of columns does change the values in the original matrix"*? Where is that in your example? If you do `b = array2D[[0], :]` and then assign `b[:] = 123` it won't change the original array either.

Comment: @a_guest I didn't try to index rows like this `array2D[[0], :]` as I didn't need to. Doing it like this `array2D[0, :] worked so I didn't try doing it with [0]. However, for columns, the only way to get a column and not a row was to include a pair of [] around the 0, else it would be transposed and the column elements will be shown as a row. But now that I tried it with the notation you showed, it does in fact create a copy and original remain unchanged like you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's just a sampling of indexing options:

```
In [431]: arr = np.arange(1,13).reshape(3,4)                                                   
In [432]: arr                                                                                  
Out[432]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Index with a scalar reduces the dimension(s):

```
In [433]: arr[1]                                                                               
Out[433]: array([5, 6, 7, 8])      # (4,)
In [434]: arr[:,1]                                                                             
Out[434]: array([ 2,  6, 10])      # (3,)
```

Those elements can still be accessed:

```
In [435]: arr[:,1] +=10                                                                        
In [436]: arr                                                                                  
Out[436]: 
array([[ 1, 12,  3,  4],
       [ 5, 16,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 20, 11, 12]])
```

Index with a list preserves the dimension(s):

```
In [437]: arr[:,[1]]                                                                           
Out[437]:                 # (3,1) 
array([[12],
       [16],
       [20]])
In [438]: arr[[1]]                                                                             
Out[438]: array([[ 5, 16,  7,  8]])     # (1,3)
```

index with a list of several items; the trailing : is optional:

```
In [439]: arr[[1,2],:]                                                                         
Out[439]: 
array([[ 5, 16,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 20, 11, 12]])
```

index with several arrays - here a 'diagonal' like selection (harder to do in MATLAB):

```
In [440]: arr[[1,2],[1,2]]                                                                     
Out[440]: array([16, 11])
```

here a block selection  (typical of MATLAB):

```
In [441]: arr[[[1],[2]],[1,2]]                                                                 
Out[441]: 
array([[16,  7],
       [20, 11]])
```

Same selection with slices (a view):

```
In [442]: arr[1:3,1:3]                                                                         
Out[442]: 
array([[16,  7],
       [20, 11]])
```

Comment: That explain it! Thank you so much! I tried to play around with the code, and it seems that it isn't possible to index with a list that contains a : , which makes sense because I see now that the indexing list is independent from the array. However, say that I write a function which constantly changes the size of the matrix by adding stuff (say the dimensions of the matrix is dependent on the function input argument), it would be really useful to be able to have that : (to indicate that we index to the end of matrix like in view) and stuff not mess with the original matrix (like in MATLAB).